# Android: how to make AnimatedImageDrawable fill the ImageView

Tags: android, scaletype, animatedimagedrawable

I am testing the new AnimatedImageDrawable from Android 9. It is quite convenient comparing to old android.graphics.Movie class.

However, I just cannot make it fill the whole ImageView with scaleType="fitXY". I tried other scaleTypes and they all worked fine. Just fitXY does not work. The animation will be rendered in its intrinsic size if I am using fitXY.

Anything else I am missing? Please help to point out.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this library 
[Android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)